# What does Patanjali say about benefits of Tribandh Pranayama?

Tags: yoga, pranayama, patanjali

I want to know what Patanjali says about benefits of Pranayama. I do not trust videos and articles about it.As they mostly talk about what they think ..
I want the verses explaining the benefits of Tribandh from 'Patanjal Yogashastra'...
Is here anyone who can share the verses and meaning too?

Comment: Patanjali Pranayama is not various types of Pranayamas as Hatha yogis show in texts. Pranayama as per patanjali is surpassing inhalation and exhalation and establish in breathlessness.

Comment: 1. Mooladhara bandha 2. Uddhiyana bhandha 3. Jalandhara bhandha after kumbhaka or rechaka

Comment: Tribandha is part of Hatha Yoga introduced by Natha Yogis and Tantra and not a part of original Patanjali Yoga Sutras and its Raja Yoga. Goal of Raja Yoga is Samadhi first but of Hatha Yoga like Tantra is Siddhis first and Samadhi later.

Comment: Tantras goal is union of shiva shakti. not siddhis.

Comment: Health is the chief idea, the one goal of the Hatha-Yogi. He is determined not to fall sick, and he never does. He lives long; a hundred years is nothing to him; he is quite young and fresh when he is 150, without one hair turned grey. But that is all. A banyan tree lives sometimes 5000 years, but it is a banyan tree and nothing more. So, if a man lives long, he is only a healthy animal. One or two ordinary lessons of the Hatha-Yogis are very useful. https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/The_First_Steps

Comment: As per Samkhya and Patanjali Yoga Sutras, Prakriti/Shakti is inert, and only Purush/Shiva exists, hence worship of Shiva/Purusha/Soul alone is done, but Aghoris/Tantriks/Hatha yogis worship Shakti/Prakriti/Body alone to gain Siddhis/occult powers and misuse it for monetary gains, longevity alone which still lead them into rebirths and darkness because they end up thinking body and siddhis are permanent. Ramkrishna Paramhansa showed that the real purpose of Tantra is Samadhi as well, not Siddhis and taming ghost, spirits,black magic as most of tantriks are infamous for these days.

Comment: If Patanjali does not say anything means your Q will never be answered. And, he has not said anything in fact.